# Generate Complex White Gaussian Noise in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, noise, digital-communications, gaussian

In the followinf code I am trying to generate a Complex Gaussian Noise:

```
n_3 = sqrt(0.1)*randn(1,K);
n_4 = sqrt(0.1)*randn(1,K);
beta_NLoS = (n_3+1i*n_4); % CN(0,0.1)
```

Does my code do as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a Circular Complex Gaussian Noise (Independent):

```
vComplexNoise = sqrt(noiseVar / 2) * (randn(1, numSamples) + (1i * randn(1, numSamples)))
```

For correlated noise you'll need to define the Co Variance Matrix and use Cholesky Decomposition.

#### Update

Following @[Stanley Pawlukiewicz](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/28715/stanley-pawlukiewicz) advise, run the following code:

```
numSamples = 100000;
noiseVar   = 4;

mA = sqrt(noiseVar / 2) * (randn(numSamples, 1) + (1i * randn(numSamples, 1)));

var(mA)
```

You should see result which is very close to `noiseVar` on the screen.

Comment: so the code i written is just a complex gaussian ,not circular?

Comment: vComplexNoise = sqrt(0.1 / 2) * (randn(1, K) + (1i * randn(1, k)))  like this?

Comment: Yep, just like you wrote above. Please mark this as answered.

Comment: but is't the gaussian distribution $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma^2  2*\pi}}$

Comment: why is't $sqrt(1/(0.1*2\pi))$ but  sqrt(0.1/2)?

Comment: The division by two is because we basically create two orthogonal noises and their variance is additive. So to have noise with variance of 'noiseVar' you need to scale it correctly.

Comment: well what i really want to ask is why the noise variance is in the numerator,but not in denominator?the noise variance ,in the gaussian distribution, is in the denominator

Comment: The formula for the Gaussian distribution with the variance in the denominator is the distribution function itself, not the random data itself! Then randn function will produce a (real) Gaussian (normal) distribution with a normalized variance of 1. So to get any other variance you need to scale the magnitude of whatever is generated by the standard deviation.  Hence sqrt(noiseVar/2). The reason for the divide by 2 as Royi pointed out is that you are generating independent sequences that will sum together. For the sum of independent random variables the variances add.

Comment: @electroniccomponent, What you ask is about the relationship between a PDF to data samples. It is another question. In this question you asked about generation of samples and you were answered. You're new to the community and we welcome you but this answer should be marked and you may start another question on PDF and I will do my best to answer it as well.

Comment: Matlab’s std and var work on complex arrays so you can generate a large array of complex random numbers and use var to check what the formula given in the answer.

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz, I took your advise and added MATLAB script to show this is the correct scaling.